# Capture the face when we blink eye

Tags: ios, machine-learning

I need some guidance that how to capture the face when we blink the eyes. I have seen the core Image framework, but it detects only after capturing the image. But I need it to be live capture.

Comment: How is that "live"? You sound like you want to detect it before you've seen it. Are you really asking for a prediction?

Comment: is this a question about a specific product or framework? if so, which?

Comment: I need to capture the image when user blinks the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know if the user blinked is to capture an image then analyze it.<sup>1</sup>

You'll probably have a loop

```
begin loop
    capture an image
    analyze image
    if user is blinking
        do something with image
    else
        discard image
    end if
end loop
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinking), people blink every 2 - 10 seconds (or less, when reading) and blinks last a around 100ms or so.  You'll have to figure out how often you need to capture an image to get a good chance of capturing a blink.

My guess is that you'll probably capture and throw away a lot of images before you get the one you want.

---

<sup>1</sup> I suppose you could use a sensitive microphone and *listen* for a blink, but that's silly.  Better to stick with capturing a lot of images and analyzing them.